# Is there such a thing as JDK incremental upgrades?

Tags: java, patch

I can not find a way to do incremental JDK upgrades. Such things are very useful to me and would be a great pain saver compared to downloading the entire JDK over again (70+ MB) uninstalling the old JDK version and installing the new one.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no incremental upgrade for the Oracle ("Standard") JDK distribution.

The JRE since Java 6 has a minimal local instalation that loads more libs when requiered.

This was always the distribution model of Sun, to install the last one and leave the old one disabled. Then from time to time user must uninstall the old versions to free up space.

Comment: That answers my questions. I guess that means I am going to start moving all my development stuff into a VM so it doesn't keep making huge messes everywhere.